# What is the importance of Enabling Code Analysis in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, code-analysis

I created a project in VS 2010. I want to convert it into VS 2013. When I build it, there is an error:

> CA0053    Error Running Code Analysis CA0053 : Unable to load rule assembly 'c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\team tools\static analysis tools\fxcop\rules\globalizationrules.dll': Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

I disabled the "Enable Code Analysis in Build" and run, then it doesn't give me an error.

1. What is the importance of Enabling Code Analysis?
2. What will happen if disable the Code Analysis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CA0053 error you get is a known issue when converting from VS 2010 to VS 2012/13.  I have listed up how to fix just that issue here:  http://geekswithblogs.net/terje/archive/2012/08/18/how-to-fix-the-ca0053-error-in-code-analysis-in.aspx

The underlying cause is that your project is bound to the specific version, and should be version independent, caused by using an absolute path to the VS 2010 binaries. 
You can change that in the project file, as described in the post.

If you want to do it manually, the basic steps are:

1. Open the project file (.csproj) in a text editor
2. Locate the lines for `<CodeAnalysisRuleDirectories> and <CodeAnalysisRuleSetDirectories>`
3. Replace them with the lines

shown here

```
<CodeAnalysisRuleDirectories>$(DevEnvDir)\..\..\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules</CodeAnalysisRuleDirectories>
```

and

```
<CodeAnalysisRuleSetDirectories>$(DevEnvDir)\..\..\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets</CodeAnalysisRuleSetDirectories>
```

As noted in the blog post, in many cases it seems you also can just delete the lines. You can try that first, if that doesn't work, do step 3 above.

Comment: How can change this  <CodeAnalysisRuleDirectories> and <CodeAnalysisRuleSetDirectories>.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the importance of Enabling Code Analysis?

So that your code gets analyzed.

> What will happen if disable the Code Analysis?

Your code won't be analyzed.

Code analysis gives you hints about your code. It is a style and security check for the code you write. 
See for more info [MSDN: Code Analysis for Managed Code Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z0aeatx.aspx) and [MSDN: Analyzing Managed Code Quality by Using Code Analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264939.aspx).